# Using Primefaces JavaScript to call a JSF method on a bean on the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

In the Primefaces User Guide it shows examples of how to make AJAX calls to the server

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/myapp/createUser.jsf',
{
    formId: 'userForm',
    oncomplete: function(xhr, status) {alert('Done');}
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to call a particular method.  My goal is to invalidate the session from the client using JavaScript.

Answer (score 18):

**RemoteCommand** is a nice way to achieve that because it provides you a JavaScript function that does the stuff (calling backing bean, refreshing, submitting a form etc., everything that command link can do).

From [PrimeFaces 3.4 documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf):

```
<p:remoteCommand name="increment" actionListener="#{counter.increment}"
out="count" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function customFunction() {
    //your custom code
    increment(); //makes a remote call
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

What I've typically done is put a hidden p:commandLink on the page, then have Javascript call the click() event on it.

```
<p:commandLink id="hiddenLink" 
   actionListener="#{bean.methodToInvoke}" style="display:none"/>
```

Then

```
$('#hiddenLink').click();
```

Comment: Great idea. But how to pass parameters to the bean?

Comment: Depends on whether those parameters are fixed or need to be adjusted client-side via javascript as well.  If they don't change, you can use f:attribute.  If they might change client-side, I've used h:inputHidden elsewhere on the form to push those along to the managed bean.

Comment: In my case, the element from <p:commandLink id="hiddenLink"> is NOT given the id "hiddenLink". Instead, it is given the id "j_idt5:hiddenLink". Therefore, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the `@PostConstruct` method of the request scoped bean which is associated with the requsted JSF page by EL like `#{bean}`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Here.
    }

}
```

---

Unrelated to the question, I only wonder why you would ever do it that way? JSF/PrimeFaces offers much nicer ways using `<f:ajax>` and `<p:ajax>` and consorts.

Is it the intent to run this during Window's `unload` or `beforeunload` events? If so, then I have to warn you that this is not reliable. It's dependent on the browser whether such a request will actually reach the server or not. More than often it won't. Use it for pure statistical or premature cleanup purposes only, not for sensitive business purposes.

Comment: I can have, at any given time, up to 5 running applications, each with its own session.  As the user switches from App to App, I keep the other applications "alive" so they don't time out from neglect. However, once the "active" App times out, then I need to "logout" the others to make sure they don't stay around.  I have 1 servlet App, 3 struts Apps and 1 JSF App.  Any one could be the "active" App at any point in time.

Comment: If they runs at the same container, just let them all share the same session. In for example Tomcat, you can achieve this by `emptySessionPath="true"` in `<Connector>` in `/conf/server.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suggested, but these are existing apps running on Weblogic.  I don't think they can guarantee that the data from one app won't collide with the others.  In other words, I don't think they can share a single session with out trampling each other.

Comment: Well, much luck with that. I would anyway reconsider a share session or at least SSO.

Comment: Currently, we have a home-grown SSO, so that, from the JSF "Portal" we can SSO into each app.  The problem is keeping them alive and then in the end logging them all out.  I suspect that I can log them out via the SSO process once I have logged them in.  Assuming the JSF app hasn't timed out.  Thanks for your help!